# add marginal frequency to three way frequency table

Tags: r, statistics, frequency

I want to create a cross frequency table of three (weighted) variables with marginal frequency.
Here is a reproducible example

```
library(stats)
library(dplyr)

data("cms_patient_care", package = "tidyr")
weights <- rnorm(252, 1,0.1)
df <- cbind(cms_patient_care, weights)
crosstabs <- xtabs(weights ~ facility_name + type + measure_abbr, data=df)
```

Now I'd like to have the marginal frequency of each *measure_abbr* by facility_name * type

So far, I've managed to have the marginal frequency of the first element of each facility_name*type with this function and addmargins()

```
marg <- function(x) {x[1]/sum(x)*100} 
crosstabs2 <- addmargins(crosstabs, margin=3, FUN = marg)
```

How can I get the rest of it ?

Comment: omitting the `margin` argument to `addmargins` should do the trick:  `addmargins(crosstabs, FUN = marg)`

Comment: @I_O doesn't work :/ It creates marginal frequency for all variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is looking to do the same, I've dropped the idea of using addmargins() because the output has to be the same dimension as stated in margin, so in order for it to work, you'd need to do the following, which is really unuseful

```
marg <- function(x) {x[1]/sum(x)*100} 
marg2 <- function(x) {x[2]/sum(x)*100} 
marg3 <- function(x) {x[3]/sum(x)*100} 
...
crosstabs2 <- addmargins(crosstabs, margin=c(3,3,3,...), FUN = c(marg, marg2, marg3,...))
```

I've managed to do the same using a small function:

- data is the output of xtabs
- variable_name is the name of the variable (between quotation marks) you want the marginal frequency of (in the example : "measure_abbr"). Note that I use position  to select variables.

```
freq_marg <- function(data, variable_name){
  df <- as.data.frame(data) %>%  
    group_by(across(1:which(colnames(.) == variable_name) - 1)) %>%
    mutate(Somme_Freq = sum(Freq)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(RowPercent = Freq / Somme_Freq)
  return(df)
}
crosstabs2 <- freq_marg(crosstabs,"measure_abbr")
```